# php5のパッケージが無くなっていて、Ubuntu 16.04 にPHPをインストールできない

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Ubuntu(Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)にてPHPを以下の通りインストールしようとしたところ、

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
パッケージ php5 は使用できませんが、別のパッケージから参照されます。
これは、パッケージが欠落しているか、廃止されたか、または別のソース
からのみ利用可能であることを意味します。

E: パッケージ 'php5' はインストール候補ではありません
```

との表示でインストールできません。この作業の前に、色々と作業したからでしょうか？
確認すべき所や、解決の参考になるようなページがあれば是非ご教示お願いしたくよろしくお願いします。

Comment: Ask Ubuntuの（重複含めた）質問が参考になりませんか
http://askubuntu.com/questions/756879/cant-install-php5-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: 自己解決した場合はご自身で回答を投稿し、承認してください。

Comment: PHP5ではなく、PHP7になったようです。
    $ sudo apt-get install php7.0
にて解決しました。

Comment: php5 を入れたいのであればそれでは解決していないのでは

Comment: 最初はPHP5しかないという考えで質問させていただきました。PHPが動けば大丈夫です。質問内容を変更させていただきます。

Comment: 結局、今はどういう状態ですか？ PHP7をインストールして解決済みという事でよいのでしょうか？ それとも、PHP5をインストールする方法を探していますか？

Comment: PHP7をインストールして解決済みです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTSからはPHP5ではなくPHP7が標準のPHPのバージョンになったようです。

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

にてPHP7がインストール可能です。

Answer (score 3):

ubuntu16.04にphp5を入れる場合

```
sudo apt-get -y purge php*
sudo apt -y autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt-get -y install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install php5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

次のコマンドを実行してみてください。

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

このコマンドでaptパッケージリストをupdateして、インストール済のモジュールをupgradeします。

Comment: updateとupgradeを実施しましたが、状況変わらずphp5はインストールできません。レポジトリの登録がおかしくなったという可能性とかないでしょうか？記憶が定かではありませんが何かインストールするためにレポジトリの追加を行った記憶があります。